# Matching comparing values in a row from four columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a function that can compare the values from a row in all the columns. And it prints a defined character for the no. of matches. Like if the 2 matches prints 'p', if 3 then 'q' and for 4 is 'r'. So what will be the function?

**The representation is a bit like that:**

[image: The representation is a bit like that].

For the column A1 to column D1, it matches 2 characters so the value is 'p'.
Subsequently, the pattern follows of matches according to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use FREQUENCY as follows:

```
=CHOOSE(MAX(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:D1,A1:D1,0),MATCH(A1:D1,A1:D1,0))),"o","p","q","r")
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you were generalising it to more than 4 columns, this might be better:

```
=CHAR(MAX(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:D1,A1:D1,0),MATCH(A1:D1,A1:D1,0)))+CODE("n"))
```